# Drupal site--quick theme, it this possible?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Sorry if this is a novice question, but just need to know if this is "possible"...My question is:

1. We have a current drupal site that is http://dpc.printing.org/  where the template you see was custom designed from scratch. Note that there is member log in to access paying member content that is ties into our database.
2. My question is: Is it possible to scrap the template from #1 above and use this template instead http://www.themesnap.com/theme-demos/gomobile/ and just add the code to the template required for member access to out database?

If yes, how much work (in terms of hours) would it take to accomplish this, roughly?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

That theme states that it is not compatible for use with existing Drupal sites.

> The GoMobile Drupal theme comes with an installation profile which
>   installs the theme using the MySQL database and website information
>   that you see in our Drupal GoMobile theme demo. This means the theme
>   needs to be installed on a new MySQL database and as a fresh Drupal
>   installation...

If the features you are interested in with that theme include things like the slideshow, the news feeds, etc. that functionality will most likely need to be duplicated within your existing Drupal installation (creating content types, creating views, placing blocks, etc.) and who knows whether the CSS in the theme will match up exactly with the configurations you create or not.

Whether the custom login using external database information was implemented correctly (using a custom module) or incorrectly (using code injected into theme templates) would decide whether using Go Mobile's install profile and moving over the custom code would be a reasonable solution.

Basically, if I were estimating this out as a client project without being able to see the back-end of the existing site or the details of the Go Mobile theme, I would treat it the same as building a site and theme from scratch, which would be 60 to 80 hours for an experienced Drupalista.

Comment: Thanks for the information, sheena_d, very helpful. I'm just trying to make sure I have all the information I need for a meeting, and to see what is possible and what is not. I'm not happy with the current theme as it is NOT flexible enough. So, you're saying that you could build a site like the Go Mobile theme (theoretically) in 60-80 hours (roughly)? One more piece of information: The http://dpc.printing.org/ site is a microsite of www.printing.org. Thank you!!!

Comment: A theme alone would take less time, but not everyone correctly understands the definition of "theme" within the context of Drupal. If your definition of theme includes Drupal configurations like content types, views, block placement, etc. then that means the project would include site building as well as theming.

Comment: If this has been helpful to you then tick it as the accepted answer.